# Сетевое взамодействие

Tags: c#, клиент-сервер, виртуальная-машина, tcpclient, tcplistener

Вечера. Передо мной стоит задача разместить сервер на виртуальной машине, а клиент на хосте. Взаимодействие реализуется через TCPClient&TCPListener. На сервере при выборе порта 3389, на котором стоит удаленный сервер ВМ появляется ошибка о том, что разрешается использование одного адреса порта. Если взять другой порт, то все будет работать.
На клиенте же я выбираю порт 3389 и клиент соединяется с сервером, но при выполнении кода появляется ошибка:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я предпринимал и менять порты и ip-адреса, даже зарезервировал часть портов, но всеравно ничего не вышло.
Клиент

```
using TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient();
await tcpClient.ConnectAsync("192.168.56.104", 3389);
var stream = tcpClient.GetStream();
int bytesRead = 10;
var response = new List<byte>();
bool flag = true;
List<NoteView> notes = new List<NoteView>();
string json_string = string.Empty;
int code = 0;
while (flag)
{

flag = Menu.MainMenu(out json_string, notes, out code);

if(code != -1)
{
    byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json_string + '\n');

    // отправляем данные
    await stream.WriteAsync(data);

    // считываем данные до конечного символа
    while ((bytesRead = stream.ReadByte()) != '\n')
    {
        // добавляем в буфер
        response.Add((byte)bytesRead);
    }
    var translation = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response.ToArray());

    Menu.OutputMenu(out notes, translation);

    response.Clear();
}
}
// отправляем маркер завершения подключения - END
await stream.WriteAsync(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("END\n"));
```

Сервер

```
var tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any,3388); 

try 
{ 
 
tcpListener.Start();    // запускаем сервер 
Console.WriteLine("Сервер запущен. Ожидание подключений... "); 

while (true) 
{ 
    // получаем подключение в виде TcpClient 
    var tcpClient = await tcpListener.AcceptTcpClientAsync(); 

    // создаем новую задачу для обслуживания нового клиента 
    _ = Task.Run(async () => await ProcessClientAsync(tcpClient)); 

    // вместо задач можно использовать стандартный Thread 
    // new Thread(async ()=>await ProcessClientAsync(tcpClient)).Start(); 
} 
} 
finally 
{ 
tcpListener.Stop(); 
} 
// обрабатываем клиент 
async Task ProcessClientAsync(TcpClient tcpClient) 
{ 
 
NoteController noteController = new NoteController(); 
var stream = tcpClient.GetStream(); 
// буфер для входящих данных 
var response = new List<byte>(); 
int bytesRead = 0; 
string translate = ""; 
while (true) 
{ 
    // считываем данные до конечного символа 
    while ((bytesRead = stream.ReadByte()) != '\n') 
    { 
        // добавляем в буфер 
        response.Add((byte)bytesRead); 
    } 
    var word = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response.ToArray()); 
     

    // если прислан маркер окончания взаимодействия, 
    // выходим из цикла и завершаем взаимодействие с клиентом 
    if (word == "END") break; 
    var resp = await noteController.Controller(word, tcpClient); 
  
    translate = JsonSerializer.Serialize(resp); 



    // добавляем символ окончания сообщения  
    translate += '\n'; 
    // отправляем перевод слова из словаря 
    await stream.WriteAsync(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(translate)); 
    response.Clear(); 
} 
tcpClient.Close(); 
}
```

Подскажите решение, так как данная проблема не позволяет решить задачу.

Comment: Логично, что клиент должен подключаться ровно к тому порту, который слушает нужный сервер, а вы почему-то написали разные порты

Comment: Это то логично, но проблема в том, что процесс резервирует порт 3389 и из-за этого я не могу использовать этот порт. Процесс к слову svchost.exe и отключить его не получается.

Comment: Зачем вам понадобился именно порт 3389? Чем не угодил порт 3388 или любой другой из 65 тысяч доступных портов?

Comment: На нем по умолчанию настроен сетевой мост ВМ. Так что я пошел по пути меньшего сопротивления и не менял настройки ВМ

Comment: И он видимо настроен специально для того самого svchost.exe, а вы решили начать с ним конфликтовать для максимального сопротивления)

Comment: И как можно поступить в этой ситуации? Перенастроить порта ВМ или выбрать порт с пометкой TIME-WAIT?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149398/discussion-between---and-andreymal).